# Create a new dataframe from a for loop with value.counts()

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe (df3) with 51 columns and managed to show the most common values in each feature with a for loop.

```
for col in df3.columns:
    print('-' * 40 + col + '-' * 40 , end=' - ')
    display(df3[col].value_counts().head(10))
```

[image]

Now I'd like to create a new dataframe called df4 with the results from the loop. That is the 10 most frequent values from all columns of df3. How can I do that?

Comment: problem is that for every column you get different IDs and I don't know what  you expect in new dataframe Maybe show expected result. Do you want only IDs in new columns or strings like `ID:count` or two columns `SND_ID` and `SND_ID_count` (and `EC_ID` and `EC_ID_count`)? Probably all of them need to use `for`-loop.

Comment: I need a new dataframe with the exact results from the loop. So SND_ID, EC_ID ...etc with 10 rows each. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get values using

```
 df4 = df3.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts().head(10).index)
```

Instead of `for`-loop I use `apply`.

Because `.value_counts()` creates `Series` which uses original `IDs` as index so I get `.index`

---

Minimal working example - because I have less values so I use `head(2)`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6], 
    'B': [4,5,6,4,2,3,4,8,8], 
    'C': [7,8,9,7,1,1,1,2,2]
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts().head(2).index)

print(df2)
```

Result

```
   A  B  C
0  6  4  1
1  3  8  7
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have less then 10 results in column then you can convert to list  expand with list which have 10 x `NaN` and after then crop it to `[:10]`

```
.head(10).index.tolist() + [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN])[:10])
```

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A': [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6], 
    'B': [4,5,6,4,2,3,4,8,8], 
    'C': [7,8,9,7,1,1,1,2,2]
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

NAN10 = [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]

df2 = df.apply(lambda col: (col.value_counts().head(10).index.tolist() + NAN10)[:10])

print(df2)
```

Result

```
     A    B    C
0  6.0  4.0  1.0
1  3.0  8.0  7.0
2  5.0  6.0  2.0
3  4.0  5.0  9.0
4  2.0  3.0  8.0
5  1.0  2.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

You can also try to conver to Series and it may add `NaN` in missing places but it will skip rows which have only `NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A': [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6], 
    'B': [4,5,6,4,2,3,4,8,8], 
    'C': [7,8,9,7,1,1,1,2,2]
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df3 = df.apply(lambda col: pd.Series(col.value_counts().head(10).index))

print(df3)
```

Result

```
   A  B    C
0  6  4  1.0
1  3  8  7.0
2  5  6  2.0
3  4  5  9.0
4  2  3  8.0
5  1  2  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. However, there is the ValueError: "arrays must all be same length" because not every feature has 10 data points. Is there a way that I can create the new dataframe with 10 entries maximum (and if there are fewer entries for a column, just indicate the shorter amount of values)?

Comment: it makes problem because you can't have one column shorter then others. You would need to add `None` or `NaN` but it makes problem. In normal list I would add list with 10 x `None` to have list with at least 10 elements - and then I would use again `[:10]`

Comment: I added example to answer